# Comparing twp pdf and highlighting the differences using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I receive two PDFs on a daily basis which have roughly the same format and data, but sometimes there are inconsistencies. Currently I have to manually check them side by side to note any errors.  How could I automate this by using Python to "highlight" the difference

```
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
from textblob import TextBlob

# Function to extract text from a PDF

def extract_text(pdf_path):


text = ""
doc = fitz.open(pdf_path)  

for page in doc:  

text += page.get_text()


return text

# Function to compare PDFs and highlight differing words in red

def compare_and_highlight(pdf_path1, pdf_path2, output_path):
text1 = extract_text(pdf_path1)
text2 = extract_text(pdf_path2)

    # Create TextBlob objects for both texts
    blob1 = TextBlob(text1)
    blob2 = TextBlob(text2)
    
    # Find the words that are different between the two TextBlob objects
    differing_words = set(blob2.words) - set(blob1.words)
    
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_path2)
    
    # Track highlighted words to avoid duplicates
    highlighted_words = set()
    
    for page in doc:
        for word in differing_words:
            if word not in highlighted_words:
                for inst in page.search_for(word):
                    # Highlight the differing word with a red background
                    highlight = page.add_highlight_annot(inst)
                    highlighted_words.add(word)  # Mark the word as highlighted
    
    # Save the modified PDF with highlighted differing words
    doc.save(output_path)
    doc.close()

# Input PDF file paths

pdf_path1 = 's1.pdf'
pdf_path2 = 's2.pdf'

# Output PDF file path with differing words highlighted in red

output_path = 'out.pdf'

# Compare PDFs and highlight differing words in red

compare_and_highlight(pdf_path1, pdf_path2, output_path)
```

This code working fine but It's highlighting the correct text also like duplicates. suppose s1 pdf contains moment word in it it's correct word and s2 pdf has moment word and also moment so it's highlighting both need to highlight only one which has differences `your text``